# about calculating row and columns in r

Tags: r

I want to ask that how to calculate mean value for specific rows and columns? For example, my dataframe is like this:

```
df:
precip  tmax    tmin  wind    date   year  month day
  1.75  18.38   6.29  2.06 1952-05-26 1952     5  26
  2.12  14.45   1.97  3.50 1952-05-27 1952     5  27
  0.00  18.98   1.95  2.82 1952-05-28 1952     5  28
  0.00  24.22   5.19  4.12 1952-05-29 1952     5  29
  2.00  21.66   6.41  1.90 1952-05-30 1952     5  30
 35.38  18.79   5.34  3.13 1952-05-31 1952     5  31
  0.62  22.64   6.79  3.50 1952-06-01 1952     6   1
  2.30  24.58   9.98  2.07 1952-06-02 1952     6   2
```

(1)How to calculate mean tmax for specific month, such as in May? the dataset is from 1950 until 2000.
I used the code:

```
df_jul = apply(df[,'month'==5],2,mean,na.rm=T)
```

but the result is: numeric(0)

If I do in another way:

```
df_jul.entry = which(df[,7]==5)
df.tmax = apply(df[c(df_jul.entry),2],2,mean,na.rm=T)
```

It throws an error: dim(X) must have a positive length
I can't check out the problem.

(2) how to calculate yearly precip? that is to say, add precip for each year.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question,

```
mean(df[df$month==5,'tmax'])
```

and for second either

```
 aggregate(precip~year, df, mean)
```

or

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[, list(precip= mean(precip)), by=year]
```

or

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
   group_by(year) %>%
   summarise(precip=mean(precip))
```

**Regarding your code**

```
df[, 'month']
#[1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6
```

But,

```
 df[, 'month'==5]
 #data frame with 0 columns and 8 rows
```

It can be

```
 df[, 'month']==5
 #[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

which may be used a row index

```
 df[df[, 'month']==5,]
```

and by specifying the column `tmax`, we get the elements of that column as a vector.

```
  df[df[, 'month']==5,'tmax']
 #[1] 18.38 14.45 18.98 24.22 21.66 18.79

 mean(df[df[, 'month']==5,'tmax'])
 #[1] 19.41333
```

By default, when we use `[` , the default is `drop=TRUE`, so if there is a single column,it will drop the dimensions to become vector.  Then `apply` won't work, so you can change `drop=FALSE` and use `apply`.  But, using `apply` for a single column is not necessary.

```
  apply(df[df[, 'month']==5,'tmax',drop=FALSE], 2, mean)
  #   tmax 
  #19.41333
```

It is the same problem for the second code

```
df_jul.entry <- which(df[,7]==5)
df[c(df_jul.entry),2]#become a vector
#[1] 18.38 14.45 18.98 24.22 21.66 18.79
```

which can be avoided by `drop=FALSE`

Comment: Thanks. It works now. Why I tried the two long methods and they didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Or with use of `plyr` you can calculate the desired values for whichever group, for example:

```
require(plyr)
df <- ddply(df, 'month', transform, MeanTmax = mean(tmax))
```

Then you can conveniently refer to this new column and subset the data for the each month, etc.